# How should I use Bootstrap 3 tokenfield with autocomplete and typeahead?

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete, typeahead.js, bootstrap-tokenfield

I have tried to reproduce the **Using Twitter Typeahead** example from http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/. I have made only a minimal modifications on the original code.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tokenfield/0.12.0/bootstrap-tokenfield.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/bloodhound.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tokenfield/0.12.0/css/bootstrap-tokenfield.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tokenfield/0.12.0/css/tokenfield-typeahead.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/theme.css"></link>
</head>

<body>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield-typeahead" value="red,green,blue" />

<script>
var engine = new Bloodhound({
  local: [{value: 'red'}, {value: 'blue'}, {value: 'green'} , {value: 'yellow'}, {value: 'violet'}, {value: 'brown'}, {value: 'purple'}, {value: 'black'}, {value: 'white'}],
  datumTokenizer: function(d) {
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
  },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
});

engine.initialize();

$('#tokenfield-typeahead').tokenfield({
  typeahead: [null, { source: engine.ttAdapter() }]
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

My problem is that the styling of auto completion and type ahead is missing. (I have a version with bower packages but it results the same.)

I have considered the

> Twitter Typeahead comes with no default styling. Make sure to include tokenfield-typeahead.css on your page.

sentence in the documentation but the mentioned css file has included.

What should I correct for proper auto completion and type ahead styling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact problem was with the included `typeahead.js` version. It works with `0.10.1`, but not with `0.11.1`. Downgrading to `0.10.1` fixes the problem.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tokenfield/0.12.0/css/tokenfield-typeahead.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tokenfield/0.12.0/css/bootstrap-tokenfield.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield-typeahead" value="red,green,blue" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.10.1/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tokenfield/0.12.0/bootstrap-tokenfield.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var engine = new Bloodhound({
                local: [{
                    value: 'red'
                }, {
                    value: 'blue'
                }, {
                    value: 'green'
                }, {
                    value: 'yellow'
                }, {
                    value: 'violet'
                }, {
                    value: 'brown'
                }, {
                    value: 'purple'
                }, {
                    value: 'black'
                }, {
                    value: 'white'
                }],
                datumTokenizer: function(d) {
                    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
                },
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
            });

            engine.initialize();

            $('#tokenfield-typeahead').tokenfield({
                typeahead: [null, {
                    source: engine.ttAdapter()
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```